# Is there a difference in what's sent back between HttpResponseMessage and Task<IHttpActionResult> using WebAPI 2?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

Here is some new code I just created with the scaffolding:

```
    [ResponseType(typeof(Exam))]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetExam(int id)
    {
        ...
        return Ok(exam);
    }
```

Previously I had code such as this:

```
    public HttpResponseMessage GetExam(int id)
    {
        ...
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, exam);
    }
```

Can someone comment on what's behind the changes. Why the suggestion is now to use return types of "Ok" and is this different from coding HttpResponseMessage? I didn't yet find any documentation on this and in particular I am wondering what the ResponseType is doing? Any advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Web API version 1, you could either return HTTP 200 by returning a value, or you would have to construct a `HttpResponseMessage` to return anything else.

In Web API 2, `IHttpActionResult` and the associated `Ok()`, `BadRequest()`, `Created()`, etc `ApiController` methods were added to simplify many situations where you simply want to respond with a different status code. Behind the scenes, Web API calls `IHttpActionResult.ExecuteAsync()` to convert it into an `HttpResponseMessage`.

For more details, see: [Action Results in Web API 2](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/action-results)

As for the `ResponseType` attribute, it's mainly there to specify the return type in actions that return `IHttpActionResult` and `HttpResponseMessage` so that Web API can generate the help documentation. Previously, this had to be done via `config.SetActualResponseType()`.

More details: [ResponseTypeAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.description.responsetypeattribute%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)